# How to make CircularProgressIndicator in jetpack compose smoother

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm build a timer that shows the minutes and seconds, and around it a used a CircularProgressIndicator for the visuals. But the CircularProgressIndicator updates jumping from second to second. Is there a way to make it run smoothly, flowing?

I tried two LauchedEffect one for the timer and one for the CircularProgressIndicator and came up with some crazy formulas but it didn't sync up very well.

here is my code so far

```
var currentTime by remember { mutableLongStateOf(totalTime) } // 10 for example
var progress by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }

// animation
val progressAnimate by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = progress,
    animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec
)

CircularProgressIndicator(
    progress = progressAnimate,
    modifier = Modifier.size(size = 300.dp),
    color = color,
    strokeWidth = 10.dp,
    strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
)

LaunchedEffect(isTimerRunning) {
    while (currentTime > 0) {
        delay(1000L)
        currentTime--
        progress = currentTime / totalTime.toFloat()
        onTimerChange(currentTime)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the animation spec [tween](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/customize#tween) and it works like this:

> tween animates between start and end values over the specified
> durationMillis using an easing curve. See Easing for more information.
> You can also specify delayMillis to postpone the start of the
> animation.

So your code would be:

```
    var currentTime by remember { mutableLongStateOf(totalTime) } // 10 for example
    var progress by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
    
    // animation
    val progressAnimate by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = progress,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 300,//animation duration
            delayMillis = 50,//delay before animation start
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
    )
    
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        progress = progressAnimate,
        modifier = Modifier.size(size = 300.dp),
        color = color,
        strokeWidth = 10.dp,
        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
    )
    
    LaunchedEffect(isTimerRunning) {
        while (currentTime > 0) {
            delay(1000L)
            currentTime--
            progress = currentTime / totalTime.toFloat()
            onTimerChange(currentTime)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. With adjustments it worked perfectly!